# Team Build on TFS 2013 not restoring all NuGet Packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, nuget

I have a Visual Studio 2017 solution that contains 6 projects.  Each project uses several NuGet packages and they are properly consolidated within the solution.  The solution builds successfully locally (Debug and Release) and will restore all NuGet packages without problem if I delete them.

After checking in the entire solution to TFS, and configuring a build (Release | Any CPU) using the default process template(TfvcTemplate.12.xaml) I queue a new build.  The build fails on the first project because a library (System.Linq.Dynamic) is not found.  The NuGet package is missing from the packages folder on the build server.

Of the 32 total NuGet packages used by the solution, there are 6 packages missing from the source folder on the build server and I cannot determine why these are missing.

I have another solution that is very, very similar to this one, and uses most of the same NuGet packages, that works fine.  The project in question is a utility project and is nearly identical.  All packages restore when building that solution and the build works fine.

I've followed the steps outlined to allow auto-restore of NuGet packages during TFS build that I've found and used before (i.e. remove NuGet.targets, and NuGet.exe; Change NuGet.Config to set disableSourceControlIntegration to true; and remove the 3 NuGet related tags from all project files).  As I mentioned, this works fine in the other solution that I have.

The only difference I can think of in the two solutions is the one that works was created in VS 2015 and the new one has been created in VS 2017.  I've compared the project files and the only real differences are the versions of some of the NuGet packages because updates have been applied.  However, the package in question is the same version and the reference is identical.

I'm not sure of any debugging logs or other helpful information on the TFS server that might provide more detailed information about the package restore that is being performed.  I'm glad to provide information if someone knows where to look.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

**I ran the build with /flp:verbosity="diagnostic" and reference to System.Linq.Dynamic in the log file for the build of the solution that works:**

Primary reference "System.Linq.Dynamic, Version=1.0.6132.35681, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null". (TaskId:25)
     Resolved file path is "D:\Builds - Agent 1\PRI.InsuranceCollection\PRI.InsuranceCollection - Release\src\PRI\PRI.InsuranceCollection\Mainline\packages\System.Linq.Dynamic.1.0.7\lib\net40\System.Linq.Dynamic.dll". (TaskId:25)
     Reference found at search path location "{HintPathFromItem}". (TaskId:25)
     The ImageRuntimeVersion for this reference is "v4.0.30319". (TaskId:25)

**Here is the reference in the log file for the build of the solution that fails:**
                          Primary reference "System.Linq.Dynamic, Version=1.0.6132.35681, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL". (TaskId:8)
14:51:56.195     5>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1635,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Linq.Dynamic, Version=1.0.6132.35681, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\Builds - Agent 2\MASC.BusinessLicense\MASC.BusinessLicense\src\MASC.BusinessLicense\Mainline\VC3.MVC.Util\VC3.MVC.Util.csproj]
                             For SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}". (TaskId:8)
                             Considered "..\packages\System.Linq.Dynamic.1.0.7\lib\net40\System.Linq.Dynamic.dll", but it didn't exist. (TaskId:8)
                             For SearchPath "{Registry:Software\Microsoft.NETFramework,v4.6.1,AssemblyFoldersEx}". (TaskId:8)
                             Considered AssemblyFoldersEx locations. (TaskId:8)
                             For SearchPath "{GAC}". (TaskId:8)
                             Considered "System.Linq.Dynamic, Version=1.0.6132.35681, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL", which was not found in the GAC. (TaskId:8)
                             For SearchPath "{RawFileName}". (TaskId:8)
                             Considered treating "System.Linq.Dynamic, Version=1.0.6132.35681, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" as a file name, but it didn't exist. (TaskId:8)
                             For SearchPath "D:\Builds - Agent 2\MASC.BusinessLicense\MASC.BusinessLicense\bin\". (TaskId:8)
                             Considered "D:\Builds - Agent 2\MASC.BusinessLicense\MASC.BusinessLicense\bin\System.Linq.Dynamic.winmd", but it didn't exist. (TaskId:8)
                             Considered "D:\Builds - Agent 2\MASC.BusinessLicense\MASC.BusinessLicense\bin\System.Linq.Dynamic.dll", but it didn't exist. (TaskId:8)
                             Considered "D:\Builds - Agent 2\MASC.BusinessLicense\MASC.BusinessLicense\bin\System.Linq.Dynamic.exe", but it didn't exist. (TaskId:8)

I don't see any explicit reference to NuGet packages being restored in either of the log files.  There are several references to the environment during the build and *EnableNuGetPackageRestore = true* appears in each of these.

Comment: Could your share the detail error part log info here?

Comment: Are you referring to the build log from the build server?  If so, does it need to be at the Diagnostic level or will Minimal work?

Comment: Better to be the Diagnostic level, you don't have to post the entire log,  (if you couldn't) just include the failed part and the log with Nuget.

Comment: I added the bit of the log file from the project that builds and the project that fails.  I don't see any reference to restoring a package in the log file.  So, I'm assuming the packages are being loaded from some cached source on the server.

Comment: Hi Keith J, Sorry for the later reply, didn't notice the comment, according to the log info,  the error just simply stand for the Nuget Package didn't get restored during tfs build pipeline and thus  xx.dll could not be found. According to your description `I have another solution that is very, very similar to this one, and uses most of the same NuGet packages, that works fine.` If you are using the same build definition, seems the issue should not related to TFS side(build template).  If you are not using the same build definition, suggest you try to use the successful one.

Comment: Besides, suggest you manually remote to the build agent and check the dll did located in corresponding location of log. Delete other nuget packages and try to use the VS in the build agent to restore all nuget packages to see if this will work properly.